# При передаче char в функцию, передается ASCII код

Tags: c#, char

**Лучше посмотрите пример, думаю там понятнее** :) Суть задачи: Дается выражение в постфиксной форме, в виде строки, сначала добавляются цифры, до знака, в стек(**выражение(123++**): если встречается знак мат. операции, то он проводит операцию над 2-мя последними числами, после чего эти числа удаляются и в стек добавляем их результат и т.д. **Решение примера**: 2+3 = 5, из стека удаляем эти числа, добавляем 5(теперь в стеке 1 и 5), опять встречаем знак '+': 1 + 5... все конец). Не знаю зачем сделал, пример, но суть проблемы, в том, что **при чтении символа из строки и передаче в функцию(класса), передается ASCII код**. Почему так происходит, что не так делаю ?

```
string str = Console.ReadLine();
char[] st = str.ToCharArray();    
foreach (char ch in str)
                {
                    if (ch != '+' && ch != '*')
                    {
                        int a = (char)ch;
                        list.Push_back((char)a);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ch == '+')
                            list.Push_back(list.Pop() + list.Pop()); // pop, сначала удаляет(перезаписав), потом возвращает символ
                        if (ch == '*')
                            list.Push_back(list.Pop() * list.Pop());
                    }
                }
foreach (var num in list)
            Console.Write(num + "  "); // должен остаться result
```

Comment: Но ведь char это и есть ascii-код символа.

Comment: char - 2 байта, utf-16, то где выводите показывает как символ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
int a = (char)ch;
```

Вы таки образом просто получаете ASCII-код символа. Причина этого простая: в символе ведь не обязательно хранится число, поэтому применять автоматическую конверсию в число нет никакого смысла.

Вам нужно вместо этого сконвертировать вручную:

```
int a = int.Parse(ch.ToString());
```

(подумайте, что должна делать программа при ошибичном вводе).

И ваш `list` должен быть стеком `int`'ов, а не `char`'ов.

Comment: Три ответа за два дня. Боюсь надеяться?..

Comment: @Igor: Это просто новогодний отпуск, так-то ничего не поменялось. Но спасибо, что помните. И поздравляю со 120K!

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, все заработало. А list он шаблонный, там просто и другие задачи есть для него.

Comment: @VladD думал, что читаю старый вопрос со старым ответом от Влада, а тут такое приятное удивление. Может быть, добьете за время отпуска 200к? :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Спасибо! Попробую добить, конечно.